# setting style for listbox

Tags: html, css, listbox

I created a `listbox` using nested div tags like so:

```
<div id="container">  
    <div id="scrollbox" >  
        <div id="content" >  
            <ul>
                <li><img src="media/images/person.png" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;Zero Users</li>
            </ul>                    
        </div>  
    </div> 
    <br><br><span id="status" ></span>      
</div>
```

I have a javascript file that governs the listbox and a css file to set the styles:

```
#container{ 
    background:white;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width:160px; 
    max-height: 150px;  
    margin:0px auto;   
    padding:20px 0;   
}
#content{
    background:white; 
}
#scrollbox{   
    width:150px;   
    height:150px;    
    overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden;   
}  

#status{background:#D8D8D8;}
```

I link to the external css file like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/jquery.listbox.css" type="text/css">
```

For the `<ul>` tag I wanted to eliminate the bullets that appear so I added the following to the css file:

```
#content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

In FireFox and Chrome this styling for the `<ul>` tag was ignored. But if I setup a separate style on the webpage itself, it works as expected. Can someone explain why it works this way but not when I put it in the css file itself?

Comment: are the other styles within the CSS file applied correctly; is the file retrieved at all? I cannot reproduce this locally, it all seems to work even when the selector is inside an external CSS file...

Comment: I did some testing to ensure the external css file was indeed being loaded by changing the background-color attribute on the div with id = "container" to yellow.  There was no change when reloaded. So the file was not loading.  Finally I discovered that the file name itself needed to be changed. The path was correct, but for whatever reason the browser didn't like the name of the file.  I had to change it from jquery.listbox.css to jquery-listbox.css  It's all working now. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty weird behaviour, but glad it worked out...